# Error OpenCV en transmision web con flask

Tags: python, flask, opencv

Soy nuevo con Opencv. Es un error un poco raro porque al princio funciona bien, luego de unos segundos es que deja de funcionar.

El error es:

```
Debugging middleware caught exception in streamed response at a point where response headers were already sent.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 870, in __next__
    return self._next()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 82, in _iter_encoded
    for item in iterable:
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/facial/app.py", line 227, in gen
    ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) /tmp/pip-wheel-qd18ncao/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:934: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !image.empty() in function 'imencode'
```

Este enlace muestra como hacer que una camara se transmita con opencv via Flask: https://manivannan-ai.medium.com/live-webcam-flask-opencv-python-26a61fee831

Aqui el codigo:

```
from flask import Flask, Response
import cv2
app = Flask(__name__)
video = cv2.VideoCapture(id) #RECIBE LA ID

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Default Message"
def gen(video):
    while True:
        success, image = video.read()
        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
        frame = jpeg.tobytes()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')
@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    global video
    return Response(gen(video),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=2204, threaded=True)
```

Se queda frisada con una imagen luego del error.

Comment: puedes leer esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129341/flask-sijax-callbacks-are-working-outside-of-request-context) de SO (ingles)

Comment: Honestamente no entinedo que hay que hacer con relacion a esa pregunta. Mira este otro https://stackoverflow.com/a/65249808/13785252 de usar **simplejpeg.encode_jpeg()**, que opinas (no se tiene que ver, sinceramente, pero veo que cambia a imencode y ahi es que esta el error).

Comment: bueno no conozco el modulo `simplejpeg` por lo que no se, puedes probar si quieres y si no te funciona edita tu pregunta añadiendo lo que haz echo

Comment: creo que no hay muchas personas que sigan la etiqueta de `opencv`, asi que tratare de hacer mi mayor esfuerzo por ayudarte

Comment: Gracias, Christian. Probe con **simplejpeg** y da error
------ ret, buffer = simplejpeg.encode_jpeg('.jpg', image)
**TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'**

Comment: dice que no le debes pasar un string, sino bytes o algun objeto, deberias visitar la documentacion del modulo y ver como funciona, tal vez algunas cosas cambiaron

Comment: No veo nada relacionado, buscare otra alternativ, pocos usan esa libreria y no hay mucho en internet.

Comment: Crees que una solucion seria reducir el size de la camara antes de pasar por opencv ... o no tiene nada que ver?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126057/discussion-between-christian-and-principe-mestizo).

Comment: Funciono cuando puse a ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image) en un while. El problema es que no transmite, aunque si transmite en local, pero no en la web.

Comment: si deseas puedes responder a tu pregunta

Comment: Gracias. Abri una nueva pregunta para el nuevo error, por si conoces la solucion: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/459451/funciona-en-local-pero-no-en-la-web-con-flask (ese codigo que coloco en la nueva pregunta funciona fluido en local, pero, aun no se transmite en la web).