# Funciona en local, pero no en la web con Flask

Tags: python, flask, opencv

Tengo un programa con Flask que funciona perfectamente en local, pero, no funciona en la web.

Segun yo, tengo toma mi web configurada, pero, no se si este problema le sale a otro. Desde la web no sale ningun error, simplemente se queda cargando.

Cuando digo "web" me refiero a mi servidor web, con apache en AWS. En local es en mi Linux.

El codigo index.html que debe ir en templates es el siguiente:

```
/* Under directory 'templates' */
<html>
  <head>
    <title>RTSP web streaming</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>RTSP web streaming</h1>
    <h3>XND-6080RV (ip:192.168.2.196)</h3>
    <h4>python webstreaming.py --ip <host ip> --port <host port></h4>
    <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
  </body>
</html>
```

El codigo de python es streaming.py

```
# import the necessary packages
from flask import Response, Flask, render_template
import threading
import argparse 
import datetime, time
import imutils
import cv2

# initialize the output frame and a lock used to ensure thread-safe
# exchanges of the output frames (useful when multiple browsers/tabs are viewing the stream)
outputFrame = None
lock = threading.Lock()
 
# initialize a flask object
app = Flask(__name__)
 
source = "rtsp://admin:password@192.168.2.196/profile2/media.smp"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(source)
time.sleep(2.0)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    # return the rendered template
    return render_template("index.html")

def stream(frameCount):
    global outputFrame, lock
    if cap.isOpened():
        # cv2.namedWindow(('IP camera DEMO'), cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
        while True:
            ret_val, frame = cap.read()
            if frame.shape:
                frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640,360))
                with lock:
                    outputFrame = frame.copy()
            else:
                continue 
    else:
        print('camera open failed')

def generate():
    # grab global references to the output frame and lock variables
    global outputFrame, lock
 
    # loop over frames from the output stream
    while True:
        # wait until the lock is acquired
        with lock:
            # check if the output frame is available, otherwise skip
            # the iteration of the loop
            if outputFrame is None:
                continue
 
            # encode the frame in JPEG format
            (flag, encodedImage) = cv2.imencode(".jpg", outputFrame)
 
            # ensure the frame was successfully encoded
            if not flag:
                continue
 
        # yield the output frame in the byte format
        yield(b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + 
            bytearray(encodedImage) + b'\r\n')

@app.route("/video_feed")
def video_feed():
    # return the response generated along with the specific media
    # type (mime type)
    return Response(generate(),
        mimetype = "multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame")

# check to see if this is the main thread of execution
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # construct the argument parser and parse command line arguments
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-i", "--ip", type=str, required=False, default='192.168.2.226',
        help="ip address of the device")
    ap.add_argument("-o", "--port", type=int, required=False, default=8000, 
        help="ephemeral port number of the server (1024 to 65535)")
    ap.add_argument("-f", "--frame-count", type=int, default=32,
        help="# of frames used to construct the background model")
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())

    t = threading.Thread(target=stream, args=(args["frame_count"],))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
 
    # start the flask app
    app.run(host=args["ip"], port=args["port"], debug=True,
        threaded=True, use_reloader=False)
 
# release the video stream pointer
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Me ayudan a resolver este problema?

Nota: si quieren probarlo, en VideoCapture pueden cambiar lo que esta dentro por (0) para que salga sus camara.

Comment: no creo que tenga sentido probarlo ya que *en local funciona*, muchas veces se tiene que hacer otras configuraciones para el servidor, casi siempre que se hace una web con Python necesitaras `unicorn` (o yo lo utilizo cuado hago deploy en Heroku)

Comment: verifica si no tienes un archivo de *logs* o una forma de ver eso, creo que todo proveedor te debe dar acceso a los *logs*

Comment: En consola de la web sale un error, un errro quye no sale en la consola del local, dice: "**[tcp @ 0x1f66d00] Port missing in uri**"

Comment: lo siento no he trabajado con AWS, mira si en la documentación hay algo a cerca de configurar el puerto o algo relacionado